# Type-Conversion With Pointers

Tags: c

I'm looking for some explanation according the output below, Im understand that there is a type-conversion.. but what happens when assigning a value to an double\int datatype? which bits are filled? and which bits the pointers points at?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double d = 2;

    double *pd = &d;
    int *pi = (int *) &d;

    printf("pi = %p, pd = %p, *pd = %f, *pi = %f\n", pi, pd, *pd,  (double) *pi);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
pi = 0x7fff5504ba70, pd = 0x7fff5504ba70, *pd = 2.000000, *pi = 0.000000
```

Comment: `*pd = 2.000000` Wat. Shouldn't that be 4?

Comment: Lot's of undefined behavior for so few lines...

Comment: the output was copy paste from my terminal.. i just wanted to know what happens behind the scenes of dereferencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pi = 0x7fff5504ba70: it is the adresse of d

pd = 0x7fff5504ba70: it is the adresse of d too, regardless of the pointer type

*pd = 2.000000: it should be 4.000000. Is it a typo ? (edit - you corrected your question so now this is correct)

*pi = 0.000000: it is the value of the bits at 0x7fff5504ba70 interpreted as an integer (because pi is a pointer to an int), and then converted to a double (because you casted to double). On my machine, a 4 as a double is 0x4010000000000000. So the first 4 bytes are all 0 (because on my machine the cpu is little-endian, a double is 8 bytes, and an int is 4 bytes).

What is happening is that pi points to the same address as pd, but only the 4 first bytes are considered when you dereference pi, and these 4 bytes are all 0.

Comment: When I first read your question, the line 4 of your code was: double d = 4; now you corrected it so double d = 2 giving *pi = 2.000000 is the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
double *pd = &d;
int *pi = (int *) &d;
```

There is no guarantee that `_Alignof(double)>=_Alignof(int)`, or that `d` just happens to be properly aligned. If it isn't, you have Undefined Behavior.

```
printf("pi = %p, pd = %p, *pd = %f, *pi = %f\n", pi, pd, *pd,  (double) *pi);
```

Now that `printf`-call is a bad beast:

- The first argument is expected to be a `void*`, but is actually a `int*`. UB.
- The second argument is expected to be a `void*`, but is actually a `double*`. UB again.
- `*pi` is an aliasing-violation. UB yet again.

In practice, things aren't nearly as dire on modern systems. Only the last one might be dangerous there, though neither is defined.

---

What you are seeing can be easily explained, assuming none of the UB above does anything "surprising" (Which might be surprising), and the initializer was actually 2 and not 4.
Also assuming that `int` is 32 bit and `double` is [IEEE double-precision floating-point-format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), saved little-endian:

```
bits
63    Sign-bit 0 (positive)
62-52 Biased Exponent (1023+1 == 1024 == 100_0000_0000<sub>2</sub>
51-0  Mantissa (All zeroes, the implicit 1 before the decimal-point is not saved, ever)
```

Thus, the low-order 32 bits are zero, which are picked up by interpreting them as an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You are lying to the compiler.

You are pointing `pi` to the address of `d`. This doesn't change the fact that `pi` points at an object that still has the type and bit representation of a `double`.

When you access `(double)*pi`, your program will try to interpret the *bits* of the double as if it was an `int`. The result will (typically) be a nonsense value which is then converted to `double`.

It may even crash your program if the pointer is not suitably aligned for accessing an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you try to interpret the internal representation of one type (here double) as the internal representation of another type (here int) you get undefined behaviour : this is not covered by any version of C specification.

Say differently, it is compiler and architecture dependent. Many modern architecture use IEEE 754 for floating point numbers, that is a mantissa (or sigificand) part and an exponent part, all in base 2.

```
Name        Common name        Base     Significand     E min   E max   Decimal Decimal
                                        digits                          digits  E max
binary32    Single precision    2       24              −126    +127    7.22    38.23
binary64    Double precision    2       53              −1022   +1023   15.95   307.95
```

But nothing forces a particular architecture to use such a representation so you code leads to UB unless you document it to be adapted to one particular system.

References :

- [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [Single-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)